# "Broken packages" installation error in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, apt-get

When I'm trying to install subversion on a Ubuntu machine using command `sudo apt-get install subversion`, it's throwing the follwoing error.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install subversion
[sudo] password for hwsui:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  subversion: Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.6.5dfsg-1ubuntu1~jaunty1~andersk1) but it is                                                                                         not going to be installed
              Depends: libapr1 but it is not installable
              Depends: libaprutil1 but it is not installable
              Depends: libmysqlclient15off (>= 5.0.27-1) but it is not installab                                                                                        le
              Depends: libneon27-gnutls (>= 0.28.2) but it is not installable
              Depends: libpq5 (>= 8.3~beta1) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Did you run apt-get update before the installation?

Comment: FYI - I did run `sudo apt-get update` and I see something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the `apt -get` with a `-f` parameter to attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies.